# SQL server - cumulative values in a column

Tags: sql-server

This is my original query:

```
    declare @symbol1 varchar(50) = 'D',
    @symbol2 varchar(50) = 'IN',
    @barDurationSeconds int = 60,
    @daysOfData int = 1

    DECLARE @bars int = datediff(second, '2000-01-01 9:30', '2000-01-01 16:00') / @barDurationSeconds * @daysOfData;

    with t as (
        select
            datediff(second, '2000-01-01', time)/ @barDurationSeconds startOfBar,
            last,
            time,
            symbol
        from ticks (nolock)
        where symbol in (@symbol1, @symbol2)
        and time < dateadd(second, 5, getdate())
        and '9:30' <= cast(time as time) and cast(time as time) <= '16:00'
    ), m as (
        select
            (a.last + b.last) / 2 Last,
            a.startOfBar,
            a.time
        from (select * from t where t.Symbol = @symbol1) a
        join (select * from t where t.Symbol = @symbol2) b on a.time = b.time
    ), r as (
        select
            *,
            row_number() over (partition by startofbar order by time desc) r
        from m
    )


    select top (@bars)
        convert(varchar(max), dateadd(second, startofbar * @barDurationSeconds, '2000-01-01'), 126) + 'Z' Time,
        last [Close],
        avg([last]) over (order by startofbar desc rows between current row and 20 following) SMA
    from r where r = 1
    order by startofbar desc
```

The output is :

```
Time                     Close                     SMA
2018-06-12T16:00:00Z    26429505.50000000000    23088291.73809523809
2018-06-12T15:59:00Z    26519811.50000000000    22839349.28571428571
2018-06-12T15:58:00Z    25759386.00000000000    22593529.54761904761
2018-06-12T15:57:00Z    25278214.50000000000    22350948.88095238095
```

**To do -**

Show the [Close] values as cumulative (sum the previous values) so I have modified the above query like this:

```
Select IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS Id, t1.Time, t1.[Close], t1.SMA
into new
from
(
select top (@bars)
    convert(varchar(max), dateadd(second, startofbar * @barDurationSeconds, '2000-01-01'), 126) + 'Z' Time,
    last [Close],
    avg([last]) over (order by startofbar desc rows between current row and 20 following) SMA
from r where r = 1
order by startofbar desc
) t1


select new.Id, new.Time, new.[Close], SUM(t2.[Close]) as sum from new
 INNER JOIN
        new t2
        ON new.Id =  t2.Id
group by new.Id, new.Time, new.[Close]
order by new.id
```

It shows the same values in both the Close columns and does not keep adding the previous ones in SUM(t2.[Close]).

Expected output:

```
Time                        Close           sum
2018-06-12T16:00:00Z    26429505.5      26429505.5
2018-06-12T15:59:00Z    26519811.5      52949317
2018-06-12T15:58:00Z    25759386        78708703
2018-06-12T15:57:00Z    25278214.5      103986917.5
```

Can you please advise what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just add a new column with `SUM(Close) OVER (ORDER BY Time ASC)` on your 1st query results.

Answer (score 1):

Use a windowed `SUM()` at the end.

```
declare @symbol1 varchar(50) = 'D',
@symbol2 varchar(50) = 'IN',
@barDurationSeconds int = 60,
@daysOfData int = 1

DECLARE @bars int = datediff(second, '2000-01-01 9:30', '2000-01-01 16:00') / @barDurationSeconds * @daysOfData;

with t as (
    select
        datediff(second, '2000-01-01', time)/ @barDurationSeconds startOfBar,
        last,
        time,
        symbol
    from ticks (nolock)
    where symbol in (@symbol1, @symbol2)
    and time < dateadd(second, 5, getdate())
    and '9:30' <= cast(time as time) and cast(time as time) <= '16:00'
), m as (
    select
        (a.last + b.last) / 2 Last,
        a.startOfBar,
        a.time
    from (select * from t where t.Symbol = @symbol1) a
    join (select * from t where t.Symbol = @symbol2) b on a.time = b.time
), r as (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by startofbar order by time desc) r
    from m
), topbars as (
        select top (@bars)
            convert(varchar(max), dateadd(second, startofbar * @barDurationSeconds, '2000-01-01'), 126) + 'Z' Time,
            last [Close],
            avg([last]) over (order by startofbar desc rows between current row and 20 following) SMA
        from r where r = 1
        order by startofbar desc
)
SELECT
    T.Time,
    T.[Close],
    [sum] = SUM(T.[Close]) OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, T.Time) ASC)
FROM
    topbars AS T
```

Comment: Getting error - ORDER BY list of RANGE window frame cannot contain expressions of LOB type.

Comment: @user1254053 your Time is varchar(max), i've edited it to order by converting to datetime.

Comment: Though it cumulate the values correctly but the result which came before "... ), topbars as ( ..."  is different with this new query i.e. the output which I am getting in original query is different with this output for [Close] values

Comment: @user1254053 I've just added another layer to your initial query to do the rolling sum. Maybe you can validate the CTE's data first.

Comment: still the same result :( The previous output is still different with this change.

Comment: Ok I made a slight change in the query and it works - thanks a lot!

Comment: I just added this line -  [sum] = SUM(r.last) OVER (ORDER BY startofbar desc) in my original query and it works :)